# Java int vs Integer - different ranges

Tags: java

I have the following Java snippet:

```
int begin=Integer.MAX_VALUE-10;
int end=Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for(int i=begin;i<=end;i++){
    System.out.println("hehe");
}
```

This code snippet will run infinitely, I can understand that this is because

```
i<**=**end
```

But some people say that `int` and `Integer` have different ranges. Is it true and why?

Comment: `int` and `Integer` do not have different ranges. `Integer` is just `int` with a class around it.

Comment: Not true. `Integer` has an `int` field inside and exposes it with `intValue`

Comment: No, it's not true. Some people say a lot of wrong things. Some people even post wrong things on StackOverflow.

Comment: Adding `i >= begin && i <= end` fixes the behavior, BTW.

Comment: "but some people says that int and Integer has different ranges." Who? Where? They're simply wrong, as `Integer` is a wrapper type for `int`.

Comment: Thank you guys, I was confused by this message from one java quiz site: "Integers are not same as int. This is an overflow scenario.. the loop is broken" http://www.topjavatutorial.com/java-quiz/java-quiz-10/ Thank you

Comment: If you print `i` instead of `"hehe"` then you'll see why it's not working.

Comment: Just to clarify: you are aware of the fact that `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` results in a _negative_ value (overflow), aren't you? That's what causes the infinite run when combined with `i<=end`.

Comment: I am just confused with quiz answer, now I understand the problem, thank you

Comment: There's one serious difference in 'range' of int and Integer. With Integer, you can express 'null', while with int you can't.

Comment: In the sentence "Integers are not same as int", "integer" is used in the mathematical sense of the set of all whole numbers. Basically, "integer" is not the same as `Integer`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. `int` and `Integer` have exactly same range.

Your program runs infinitely because when you add `1` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you get numeric overflow and result will be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Which in turn less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

If this is practical problem, I suggest you to use `long` and `Long` instead of `int` and `Integer`

Comment: I understand it, thank you, was just confused by a message. See my comment to previous post please. Thanks